# When does tensorlfow raise "Do not pass `graph_parents`."?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I'm running TensorFlow version 2.3.1 and was wondering in which case does it raise the warning:

> Do not pass 'graph_parents'.  They will  no longer be used.

I am not using any kind of unconventional graph-like structure, and I compute all gradients using `GradientTape`.

Comment: You could use Python warning filters to turn that warning into an error you get a traceback for.

Comment: how exactly would I do that?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Comment: @Gepeto97,  Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.3/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg/linear_operator.py) help you?